# Has Dan Abnett said that The Anarch is his last Ghosts book?

Tags: warhammer-40k, gaunts-ghosts

After writing The Anarch has the author said anywhere that this is his final book in the series?

I mean the last 3 books are together called "The Victory"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NO**

From an interview with Abnett on [Track of Words](https://www.trackofwords.com/2019/01/16/rapid-fire-dan-abnett-talks-anarch/):

> **Track of Words: What’s the elevator pitch summary for Anarch?**
>
> Dan Abnett: This is the climax of the fourth arc – The Victory – and the culmination of the battle for Urdesh (and the fight against the archenemy Magister, Sek). It’s not the last book in the series, but it’s a very major piece of punctuation, completing some story strands that have been running for years. A very ‘big’ book (incidentally, the longest novel I’ve written, but that’s not what I mean by big). Essential reading for any Ghosts fan.